# Start apache-felix 4.2.1 with iPOJO on Android

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, ipojo

I try to start apache-felix 4.2.1 with iPOJO 1.11.0 on Android 4.+.

config.properties standard with added:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra= \
android, \
android.accessibilityservice, \
...
android.support.v4.view.accessibility, \
android.support.v4.widget
```

start command:

```
/system/bin/dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:/system/framework/core.jar -classpath bin/felix.jar org.apache.felix.main.Main
```

After start it write:

```
Problem creating boot delegation class loader: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

1) With this problem all my applications working, but maybe someone knows how to repair this problem? (Then starts apache felix from [osgi-android.zip](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html) - have not this problem.)

When start Apache Felix iPOJO (1.11.0) throws error:

```
! ERROR: Bundle org.apache.felix.ipojo [14] Error starting file:/data/local/feli
x/felix-framework-4.2.1a/bundle/org.apache.felix.ipojo-1.11.0.jar (org.osgi.fram
ework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.apache.felix.ipojo [1
4].)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Logger$ConsoleLogSer
vice
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.util.Logger.<clinit>(Logger.java:51)
        at org.apache.felix.ipojo.extender.internal.Extender.start(Extender.java
:123)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAct
ion.java:645)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2146)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2064)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1291)

        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStart
LevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

2) How to start org.apache.felix.ipojo-1.11.0.jar properly? [iPOJO supports Android with restrictions](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-ipojo-supportedvms.html)

Bundles:

```
! lb
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (4.2.1)
    6|Active     |    1|jcl-over-slf4j (1.7.5)
    8|Active     |    1|Logback Classic Module (1.0.13)
    9|Active     |    1|Logback Core Module (1.0.13)
   10|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (1.6.6)
   11|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.12.0)
   12|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.10.0)
   13|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
   14|Resolved   |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO (1.11.0)
   15|Active     |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO API (1.11.0)
   16|Active     |    1|Apache Felix iPOJO Gogo Command (1.11.0)
   17|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Log Service (1.0.1)
   18|Active     |    1|osgi.cmpn (4.2.0.200908310645)
   21|Active     |    1|slf4j-api (1.7.5)
```

### **UPDATE:**

use dex2jar-0.0.9.15 classes.dex->classes.jar

classes.jar contains:

```
org/
org/apache/
org/apache/felix/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/Factory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/IPojoFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/TrackerCustomizer.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/ComponentFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/ComponentInstance.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/ConfigurationException.class
org/osgi/
org/osgi/service/
org/osgi/service/cm/
org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationListener.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/ConfigurationTracker.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/ConstructorInjector.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/ContextListener.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/ContextSource.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/ErrorHandler.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/EventDispatcher.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/FactoryClassloader.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/FactoryStateListener.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/FieldInterceptor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/Handler.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/HandlerFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/InstanceStateListener.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/InstanceManager.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/HandlerManager.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/architecture/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/architecture/ComponentTypeDescription.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/HandlerManagerFactory$HandlerTypeDescription.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/HandlerManagerFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/IPOJOServiceFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/ServiceContext.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/IPojoContext.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/IPojoFactory$NameGenerator.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/IPojoFactory$DefaultNameGenerator.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/IPojoFactory$RequiredHandler.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/IPojoFactory$RetryNameGenerator.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/MethodInterceptor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/MissingHandlerException.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/Nullable.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/Pojo.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/PolicyServiceContext.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/PrimitiveHandler.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/architecture/InstanceDescription.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/PrimitiveInstanceDescription.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/PrimitiveTypeDescription$InheritanceInspector.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/PrimitiveTypeDescription.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/UnacceptableConfiguration.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/architecture/Architecture.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/architecture/CustomHandlerInfo.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/architecture/HandlerDescription.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/architecture/PropertyDescription.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/configuration/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/configuration/Configuration.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/configuration/Instance$FluentList.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/configuration/Instance$FluentMap.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/configuration/Instance$Pair.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/configuration/Instance$Property.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/configuration/Instance.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/context/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/context/ServiceReferenceImpl.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/context/ServiceRegistrationImpl.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/context/ServiceRegistry$1.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/context/ServiceRegistry$ListenerInfo.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/context/ServiceRegistry.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/context/StringMap$StringComparator.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/context/StringMap.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/interceptors/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/interceptors/DependencyInterceptor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/interceptors/ServiceRankingInterceptor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/ComparatorBasedServiceRankingInterceptor.
class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/DependencyProperties.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/EmptyBasedServiceRankingInterceptor.class

org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/interceptors/ServiceTrackingInterceptor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/FilterBasedServiceTrackingInterceptor.cla
ss
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/ServiceReferenceManager$1.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/ServiceReferenceManager$2.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/ServiceReferenceManager$3.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/ServiceReferenceManager$ChangeSet.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/ServiceReferenceManager$RankingResult.cla
ss
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/ServiceReferenceManager.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/ServiceReferenceUtils.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/interceptors/TransformedServiceReference.class

org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/impl/TransformedServiceReferenceImpl.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/interceptors/DefaultDependencyInterceptor.clas
s
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/interceptors/DefaultServiceRankingInterceptor.
class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/interceptors/DefaultServiceTrackingInterceptor
.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/dependency/interceptors/ServiceBindingInterceptor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/Declaration.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/ExtensionDeclaration.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/InstanceDeclaration.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/Status.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/TypeDeclaration.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/builder/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/builder/FactoryBuilder.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/builder/FactoryBuilderException.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/Lifecycle.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/AbstractService.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/BundleProcessor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/queue/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/queue/Job.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/DefaultJob.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/Extender$1.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/Extender.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/queue/QueueService.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/LifecycleQueueService.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/builder/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/builder/ReflectiveFactoryBuilder.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/declaration/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/declaration/AbstractDeclaration$1.class

org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/declaration/AbstractDeclaration.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/declaration/DefaultExtensionDeclaration
.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/declaration/DefaultInstanceDeclaration.
class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/declaration/DefaultTypeDeclaration.clas
s
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/linker/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/linker/DeclarationLinker.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/linker/ManagedType$1.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/linker/ManagedType$ExtensionSupport$1.c
lass
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/linker/ManagedType$ExtensionSupport.cla
ss
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/linker/ManagedType$InstanceSupport$1.cl
ass
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/linker/ManagedType$InstanceSupport.clas
s
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/linker/ManagedType.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ChainedBundleProcessor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ComponentsBundleProcessor$1.c
lass
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ComponentsBundleProcessor$Com
ponentsAndInstances.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ComponentsBundleProcessor.cla
ss
org/objectweb/
org/objectweb/asm/
org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.class
org/objectweb/asm/FieldVisitor.class
org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.class
org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationVisitor.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/
org/objectweb/asm/commons/EmptyVisitor.class
org/objectweb/asm/Opcodes.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ConfigurationAnnotationScanne
r.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ConfigurationProcessor$1.clas
s
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ConfigurationProcessor$Compon
entsAndInstances.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ConfigurationProcessor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ExtensionBundleProcessor.clas
s
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ForwardingBundleProcessor.cla
ss
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/QueuingActivationProcessor$1.
class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/QueuingActivationProcessor.cl
ass
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/processor/ReverseBundleProcessor.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/QueueNotifier.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/AbstractQueueService.class
org/osgi/service/cm/ManagedService.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/ExecutorQueueService.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/GroupThreadFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/queue/JobInfo.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/JobInfoCallable.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/NamingThreadFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/PrefixedThreadFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/Statistic.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/SynchronousQueueService$Immediate
Future.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/SynchronousQueueService$Exception
Future.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/SynchronousQueueService.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/debug/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/debug/ReplayQueueEventProxy$Queue
Event.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/debug/ReplayQueueEventProxy$Enlis
tedQueueEvent.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/debug/ReplayQueueEventProxy$Execu
tedQueueEvent.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/debug/ReplayQueueEventProxy$Faile
dQueueEvent.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/debug/ReplayQueueEventProxy$Start
edQueueEvent.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/queue/debug/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/queue/debug/QueueEventProxy.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/queue/QueueListener.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/debug/ReplayQueueEventProxy.class

org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/pref/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/pref/PreferenceSelection.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/pref/HeaderPreferenceSelection.cl
ass
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/pref/Preference.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/pref/PreferenceQueueService$1.cla
ss
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/pref/PreferenceQueueService.class

org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/pref/enforce/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/pref/enforce/ForwardingQueueServi
ce.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/internal/queue/pref/enforce/EnforcedQueueService
.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/extender/queue/Callback.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/architecture/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/architecture/ArchitectureHandler.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/configuration/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/configuration/ConfigurationHandler.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/configuration/ConfigurationHandlerDescription.cl
ass
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/configuration/ConfigurationListener.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/AggregateDependencyInjectionType.clas
s
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/Dependency$1.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/Dependency$DynamicProxyFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/Dependency$NullableClassLoader.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/Dependency$SmartProxyFactory.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/DependencyModel.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/Dependency.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Callback.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/DependencyCallback.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/DependencyConfigurationChecker.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/DependencyDescription.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/DependencyStateListener.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/DependencyHandler.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/DependencyHandlerDescription.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/NullableObject.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/ProxyGenerator.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/ServiceCollection$1.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/ServiceCollection$ServiceIterator.cla
ss
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/ServiceCollection.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/ServiceUsage$Usage.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/dependency/ServiceUsage.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/lifecycle/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/lifecycle/callback/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/lifecycle/callback/LifecycleCallback.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/lifecycle/callback/LifecycleCallbackHandler.clas
s
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/lifecycle/controller/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/lifecycle/controller/ControllerHandler.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/CreationStrategy.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedService$1.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedService$FactoryStrategy.
class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedService$PerInstanceStrat
egy.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedService$ServiceControlle
r.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedService$SingletonStrateg
y.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedService.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedServiceDescription.class

org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedServiceHandler.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedServiceHandlerDescriptio
n.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/ProvidedServiceListener.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/strategy/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/strategy/ConfigurableCreationStr
ategy.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/strategy/ErrorPrintingServiceFac
toryProxy.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/handlers/providedservice/strategy/ServiceObjectFactory.cl
ass
org/apache/felix/ipojo/metadata/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/metadata/Attribute.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/metadata/Element.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/parser/
org/apache/felix/ipojo/parser/FieldMetadata.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/parser/ManifestMetadataParser.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/parser/MethodMetadata.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/parser/ParseException.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/parser/ParseUtils.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/parser/PojoMetadata.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/ContextSourceManager$1.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/ContextSourceManager$SourceTracker.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/ContextSourceManager.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/DependencyMetadataHelper.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/DependencyModel$1.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/DependencyModel$DependencyEventType.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/DependencyModel$ServiceBindingHolder.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/DependencyModelListener.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Fields.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/InstanceConfigurationSource.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/InvocationResult.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Log.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Logger$1.class
org/osgi/service/log/
org/osgi/service/log/LogService.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Logger$ConsoleLogService.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Logger.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Methods.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Property.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Reflection.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/SecurityHelper.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/ServiceLocator.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/ServiceReferenceRankingComparator.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/StreamUtils.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/SystemPropertiesSource.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Tracker$Tracked.class
org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Tracker.class
org/objectweb/asm/AnnotationWriter.class
org/objectweb/asm/Attribute.class
org/objectweb/asm/ByteVector.class
org/objectweb/asm/ClassAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.class
org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.class
org/objectweb/asm/Edge.class
org/objectweb/asm/FieldWriter.class
org/objectweb/asm/Frame.class
org/objectweb/asm/Handler.class
org/objectweb/asm/Item.class
org/objectweb/asm/Label.class
org/objectweb/asm/MethodAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/MethodWriter.class
org/objectweb/asm/Type.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/LocalVariablesSorter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/GeneratorAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/AdviceAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/AnalyzerAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/CodeSizeEvaluator.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/InstructionAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/JSRInlinerAdapter$Instantiation.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/JSRInlinerAdapter$Subroutine.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/JSRInlinerAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/Method.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/Remapper.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/RemappingAnnotationAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/RemappingClassAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/RemappingFieldAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/RemappingMethodAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/RemappingSignatureAdapter.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/SerialVersionUIDAdder$Item.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/SerialVersionUIDAdder.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/SimpleRemapper.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/StaticInitMerger.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/TableSwitchGenerator.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/TryCatchBlockSorter$1.class
org/objectweb/asm/commons/TryCatchBlockSorter.class
org/osgi/service/cm/Configuration.class
org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationAdmin.class
org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationEvent.class
org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationException.class
org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationPermission.class
org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationPermissionCollection$1.class
org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationPermissionCollection.class
org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationPlugin.class
org/osgi/service/cm/ManagedServiceFactory.class
org/osgi/service/log/LogEntry.class
org/osgi/service/log/LogListener.class
org/osgi/service/log/LogReaderService.class
```

Then dexing have warning, but not for ConsoleLogService warning.

dx --dex --output=./classes.dex ./org.apache.felix.ipojo-1.11.0.jar:

```
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationPermissionCollection$1) that doesn't come with
 an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from a redefinition of classes. Dalvik does not support having classes define twice (even in two different bundles or classloaders). That means you can't follow the good practice rules of OSGi you generally use:

- each class must be defined once and only once
- each exported package must be defined only once (regardless its version)

I suppose you have another bundle exporting the configuration admin package or the log service package (such as the OSGi Compendium, or an implementation of these services). In this case you need to transform a bit the iPOJO bundle by removing the export of these packages as well as the included classes. If you can package iPOJO yourself, open the pom file and remove:

```
<!-- Compendium packages -->
org.osgi.service.cm; version=1.3,
org.osgi.service.log; version=1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you 'dex' the iPOJO bundle ? It looks it can't find the inner class.

Comment: yes org.apache.felix.ipojo-1.11.0.jar contain classes.dex (484,288 bytes; MD5: 85E488E2D7B34EEDDF42D6AFE349F8E8)

Comment: see updated data please: classes.dex contains org/apache/felix/ipojo/util/Logger$ConsoleLogService.class. Dexing logs warning.